# Are non-degenerate eigenfunctions orthogonal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue

**Orthogonal** eigenfunctions of the same Hermitian operator have *different* eigenvalues.

Meanwhile, **degenerate** eigenfunctions share the *same* eigenvalue.

Any linear combination of two degenerate eigenfunctions gives an eigenfunction with the same eigenvalue. So:

Are **non-degenerate** eigenfunctions necessarily **orthogonal** and **linearly independent**?

And another question: Are linear dependance and orthogonality different properties?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213737/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I initially misread your question.

> Are **non-degenerate** eigenfunctions necessarily orthogonal and linearly independent?

Yes. If $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ are eigenvectors of a self-adjoint operator $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$, then

$$\langle \vec v_1,A\vec v_2\rangle =  \langle A\vec v_1,\vec v_2\rangle$$
$$\lambda_2 \langle \vec v_1,\vec v_2\rangle = \lambda_1 \langle \vec v_1,\vec v_2\rangle \iff (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)\langle \vec v_1,\vec v_2\rangle = 0$$
Since $\lambda_1-\lambda_2\neq 0$, we must have that $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ are orthogonal, which implies linear independence as we show now.

> Are linear dependence and orthogonality different properties?

Yes.  If two nonzero vectors are orthogonal they must be linearly independent, but the reverse is not true.  The proof of the latter is immediate (say, pick $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $\pmatrix{1\\1}$ from $\mathbb R^2$).  To prove the former, assume that $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ are orthogonal, and let $\vec v = \alpha \vec v_1 + \beta \vec v_2 = 0$. We seek to show that $\alpha=\beta=0$.  To do this, note that

$$\Vert \vec v\Vert^2 = \langle \alpha \vec v_1+\beta \vec v_2,\alpha \vec v_1 + \beta \vec v_2\rangle = |\alpha|^2 \Vert \vec v_1\Vert^2 + |\beta^2| \Vert \vec v_2\Vert^2=0$$
where we have used the orthogonality of $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$.  Since both terms in the sum are manifestly non-negative, they must both be zero; since $\Vert \vec v_1\Vert$ and $\Vert \vec v_2\Vert$ are nonzero, we must have that $\alpha=\beta=0$.

---

I initially misread the question, but in the interest of completeness I'll keep my initial answer.

> Are **degenerate** eigenfunctions necessarily orthogonal and linearly independent?

No, not necessarily.  The most obvious counterexample is that of the identity operator; *every* vector is an eigenvector of the identity operator with eigenvalue $1$, but obviously not every pair of vectors is orthogonal or linearly independent.

If an operator has a degenerate eigenvalue, then the corresponding eigen*space* has dimension greater than 1.  For a bit of intuition, you might consider the following $3\times 3$ matrix:
$$A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2}$$
The eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$ is the entire *plane* which is orthogonal to $(1,0,0)^T$.  If you choose any two linearly independent vectors $\vec v_1,\vec v_2$ from that plane, then $\mathcal B = \left\{\pmatrix{1\\0\\0},\vec v_1,\vec v_2\right\}$ constitutes a basis for the space, but $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ need not be orthogonal.  The key point is that we **may** choose them to be if we wish.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But consider your example of linearly independent, non-orthogonal eigenvectors (1,0) and (1,1). If they have different eigenvalues they must be orthogonal, but they're not. And if they have the same eigenvalue, they must be degenerate, and therefore, linearly dependent, but they're not. So what are their eigenvalues?

Comment: @pll04 It doesn't make sense to ask what their eigenvalues are unless you specify an operator.  Let's choose the identity operator, so both of their eigenvalues are 1. "And if they have the same eigenvalue, they must be degenerate, and therefore linearly dependent." The fact that they belong to the same eigenspace does not imply that they are linearly dependent if the dimensionality of that eigenspace is >1.

Comment: So degeneracy does not imply linear dependance? But since non-degeneracy always implies orthogonality, wouldn't that mean that linearly independent non-orthogonal eigenvectors must always have the same eigenvalue? Since same eigenvalue always means orthogonality

Answer (score 0):

> Are non-degenerate eigenfunctions necessarily orthogonal and linearly independent?

Yes. It is an elementary exercise in Linear Algebra to show that the eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues of a self-adjoint (Hermitian) operator are orthogonal.

> Are linear dependance and orthogonality different properties?

Yes. All orthogonal eigenvectors are linearly independent, but not necessarily vice-versa.

Comment: So if two eigenfunctions are linearly independent but not orthogonal, would their eigenvalues be different or the same?

Comment: They could be or they could not; there is no general rule that says they must be same or different in that case.

Comment: But if the eigenvalues are different, mustn't the eigenfunctions be orthogonal?

Comment: Yes, that is true.